# is Root a minus number undefined

Tags: roots

Assume that we have a function $f$ such that $f(x) = \sqrt x$
Is a domain of $-1$ undefined.
I thought it wouldn’t because the answer would be $i\sqrt x$.
However, apparently, it is undefined. Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: If the domain is that of *reals*, square root is not defined for negative numbers. If the domain is that of *complex*...

Comment: I couldn’t understand what you meant by that of complex and that of reals. Could you explain? Thank you !

Comment: Do you know [Real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) and [Complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) ?

Comment: Formally, a function is very explicitly defined by 1) the domain of the function, 2) the codomain of the function, 3) a rule to follow for mapping an input to an output.  Do not confuse the function $f$ whose domain is $\Bbb R_{\geq 0}$ and codomain is $\Bbb R$ given by $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$  and the function $f$ whose domain is $\Bbb C$ whose codomain is $\Bbb C$ given by $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$.

Comment: If you were only told that $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ with absolutely no additional context... then the correct answer to whether $f(-1)$ is defined is "*it depends.*"  If you are able to figure out from context that the domain is meant to be all reals or just the non-negative reals then you say $f(-1)$ is undefined.  If you learn that the domain is all complex numbers then you say $f(-1)$ is defined and is equal to $i$.  If it is any other context then you must examine that situation more closely.

Comment: Okay thank you. That part is not given in the question, and there is no choice as it depends. Therefore, I’ll assume that the domain is real

Answer (score 0):

Both.

The *real* square root function is $$\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R^+:x\to\sqrt x.$$

$-1$ is not in the domain and $\sqrt{-1}$ undefined.

The *complex* square root is

$$\mathbb C\to\mathbb C:z\to\sqrt z$$ and requires to choose a specific branch (usually, $\sqrt{-1}=i$).